# Substituting one inequality in another inequality

Tags: inequality

Suppose I have two inequalities:

$$f(n) \leqslant a × g(n)$$
and

$$2^{f(n)} \leqslant b × 2^{g(n)}$$

How can I substitute the equation 1 in equation 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, if you want to make sure you obtain a true inequality. Your second inequality is equivalent to $$f(n)\leq \log_2 b+g(n)$$
and this could be stronger than your first inequality, meaning 
$$f(n)\leq \log_2b+g(n)\leq a\cdot g(n).$$

Comment: Exactly what my doubts were. I am confused with this problem now.